# Amazon Redshift COPY command slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to copy ~3000 .csv.gz files into Amazon Redshift table from Amazon S3 bucket. The number of table columns is about 150 and size of one file is in range 1-10 megabytes.

```
COPY table
FROM 's3://bucket/folder/'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
IGNOREHEADER 1
GZIP
DELIMITER ',';
```

The problem is that this operation is very slow, takes too much time to finish. Is there any way to tune performance?

Comment: How many nodes, and what type of nodes, are in your cluster? You could temporarily increase the number of nodes, then reduce it down afterwards. (It causes a bit of re-shuffling in the backend, but makes the load faster since loading works in parallel across multiple nodes.) Also, what sort of `SORTKEY` is on the table? Interleaved sorting can take a long time.

Comment: What performance are you seeing now, on what kind of nodes?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i have only one ds2.xlarge instance. I guess the problem is in the SORTKEY (two timestamps, one unique hashed id)

Comment: No, the "problem" is probably that you have a lot of files being processed on one node. It can't parallelize the workload much with only one node. How long does it take, and how long would you _like_ it to take? How many rows in total? See also: [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Loading Data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html)